# Firebase emulator doesn't display ReactsJS components

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web

I'm trying to host a ReactJS App on Firebase. The site is rendered correctly via normal ReactJS `npm start` but the ReactJS components don't show when started via the Firebase emulator with `firebase emulators:start`

ReactJS (localhost)

[image: ReactJS (localhost)]

Firebase emulator (localhost)

[image: Firebase emulator (localhost)]

I've tried changing public to build as seen in the link below, but then I get a blank screen with `/cannot get`:

[firebase deploy gives welcome screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045376/firebase-deploy-gives-welcome-screen)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you opened your browser console to check if the index.html page loads the javascript bundle containing your React code?

Comment: @LouisCoulet Thanks for your help. I just checked, and no it doesn't load the javascript bundle containing the React code. How do I load it?

Comment: Your index.html should contain a *script* tag, this *script* tag should have a *src* attribute containing a URL, your bundle should be accessible by the browser at this URL.